# How to create action sequence in an app like in a spritekit game?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to have a guy move to the left, turn around and then move to the right. I know how to do this in Spritekit, which is using SKAction sequence. However, I am really having a hard time doing it in a app rather than a game. What I have now will result in the guy moving and turning at the same time:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, delay: 0.0, options: [ .Repeat, .Autoreverse, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.guy.center.x -= 130
        }, completion: nil)

    //    
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, delay: 5.0, options: [ .CurveEaseInOut, .Repeat, .Autoreverse ], animations: {
        self.guy.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
        }, completion:nil )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the completion handler if the first animation to fire the second animation.

Put that into a function and fire this function with a timer to create a loop

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, delay: 0.0, options: [ .Repeat, .Autoreverse, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
    self.guy.center.x -= 130
    }, completion: {
         UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, delay: 0.0, options: [ .CurveEaseInOut, .Repeat, .Autoreverse ], animations: {
            self.guy.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
    }, completion:nil )
})
```